# Rails scaffold not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, activescaffold

In one of my RoR projects, I run "rails generate scaffold project title:string description:text" 
on my terminal and here what it throws at me:

```
/Users/Mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-   5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load': no implicit  conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
from /Users/Mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
from /Users/Mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
from /Users/Mika/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Mika/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I couldn't figure out what went wrong, I generated few scaffolds before, but I couldn't get it to work on this one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your command looks fine. However, there appears to be an issue with RVM and/or Bundler. Have you tried prefixing that command with `bundle exec`? You may want to try opening a new terminal (moving into the project directory, if necessary) and running `rvm use 2.4.0 && bundle install && bundle exec rails generate scaffold project title:string description:text`.

Comment: name your resource with a capital letter, i.e. `Project` instead of `project`